# Wordpress PHP - how do you move post thumbnail image to below post title and excerpt

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to rearrange the layout of my 'recent posts' in Wordpress. I would like the post's thumbnail image to appear below the 'post header' and 'excerpt'. I don't know PHP and wherever I move the code it doesn't seem to work.

If anyone could please advise me on what code to move and where would be a great help!

```
                       <?php }

                        }

                        else {
                            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'portfolio-thumb', array('title' => '')) . '</a>'; }
                        }

                    ?>

                        <div class="post-header">
                            <h1 class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>    
                            <span class="meta-author"><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> </span> <span class="meta-category"> | <?php the_category(', '); ?> </span> <span class="meta-comment-count"> | <a href="<?php comments_link(); ?>">
                            <?php comments_number( __('No Comments',NECTAR_THEME_NAME), __('One Comment',NECTAR_THEME_NAME), '% '. __('Comments',NECTAR_THEME_NAME) ); ?></a> </span>
                        </div><!--/post-header-->

                        <?php 
          $excerpt_length = (!empty($options['blog_excerpt_length'])) ? intval($options['blog_excerpt_length']) : 30; 
                        echo '<div class="excerpt">' . nectar_excerpt($excerpt_length) . '</div>';

                    } // default style
```

Comment: `if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'portfolio-thumb', array('title' => '')) . '</a>'; }` this your target line and if you want more help please post the full template that you have already

Comment: The template is too big to post, but yes that is the target line

Comment: at lease post  what before the `else`  to understand  what is the main condition that you have

Comment: Does this help? http://codepad.org/SlWdofVm

Comment: upload the file to dropbox or google drive and share the link here

Comment: Thank you! https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hLy4-OsaHj36IcsAAi93V7fpIKUAhdMg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178622/discussion-between-kashalo-and-darren-baker).

Answer (score 0):

You can save the string in a variable. Then echo the variable where you want the image to appear:

First define the variable outside of your `if/else` scope (in the top of the file).

```
$thumbnail = '';
```

Then in the `else` scope, fill the variable with the HTML.

```
else {
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
        $thumbnail = 
            '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' .
                get_the_post_thumbnail(
                    $post->ID, 
                    'portfolio-thumb', 
                    array('title' => '')
                ) . 
            '</a>'; 
    }
}
```

Now echo it where you want it to appear (below excerpt).

```
echo $thumbnail;
```